# "Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when trying to hydrate tanstack-query with nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-query, tanstackreact-query

```
import { Hydrate, dehydrate } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { getPosts } from "./api/api";
import getQueryClient from "./getQueryClient";
import Posts from "@/components/Posts";

export default async function PostsWrapper() {
const queryClient = getQueryClient();
await queryClient.prefetchQuery(["posts"], getPosts);
const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);

return (
 <Hydrate state={dehydratedState}>
   <Posts />
 </Hydrate>
 );
 }

export const getPosts = async () => {
try {
const data = await axios.get("https://forums-api.onrender.com/posts");
return data;
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
};

"use client";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { getPosts } from "../app/api/api";
import PostCard from "@/components/PostCard";
import { Card, Input, Select, SelectItem, Spinner } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { Categories, Post } from "@/types/types";
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

const Posts = () => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
queryKey: ["posts"],
queryFn: getPosts,
});
//  rest of the component
}
```

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Call Stack
String.replace

Trying to fetch data on the server instead of the client so I went with the hydrate method but have no idea why im getting this error, worked fine fetching on client. I tried the initialData method too and same result. Using nextjs with app router.

CodeSandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Oz996/forums-hydrate/main?file=%2Fclient%2Fapp%2FPostsWrapper.tsx%3A1%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00073j6kjihe75xf%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00033j6kznedpybm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00053j6kbke0p9wx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00063j6kmxgygaul%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clnj46n6o00033j6kznedpybm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00033j6kznedpybm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnj481ub00g83j6k6g2extj9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00023j6kc7ldelj2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.gitattributes%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fserver%252F.env%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46s94007w3j6kwc2uh7ap%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fclient%252Fapp%252FPostsWrapper.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj481ub00g83j6k6g2extj9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clnj46n6o00063j6kmxgygaul%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00063j6kmxgygaul%2522%257D%252C%2522clnj46n6o00053j6kbke0p9wx%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00043j6kk1yi4xc5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clnj46mpc0027e8is0rmje2ze%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00053j6kbke0p9wx%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnj46n6o00043j6kk1yi4xc5%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D

Comment: code looks fine; please show a full reproduction like codesandbox or stackblitz

Comment: @TkDodo Sure, here: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Oz996/forums-hydrate/main?file=%2Fclient%2Fapp%2FPostsWrapper.tsx%3A1%2C1&workspaceId=5dc0734d-d0b3-4842-acd4-16b6d64144c9

Comment: is this a private repo? getting "Unable to access this workspace"

Comment: @TkDodo Sorry first time using codesandbox, I updated the post with a link that should let you view the project

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue just last week, spent 3-4 days on it. All the youtube videos and online blogs along with official tanstack query documentation did the exact same thing and it worked, except mine.

Surprisingly, I found out that the issue is with none other than the axios(no idea why). If I use axios to fetch data, it throws error, but if I fetch data using fetch api, it works fine. I have no idea why this happens, but at least my project is working fine right now.

Try fetch instead of axios, and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: replacing `axios` with `fetch` worked like a charm. LOL

Answer (score 0):

returning data from axios solved the issue for me like:
`axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)`